# Publishing interactive scientific results in Python

Tags: javascript, python, django, d3.js

I'm not sure if this question fits in this community, but I don't know where to ask it.

I don't have a background in programming for web, but recently I started a web project that uses, for example, `Leaflet.js`, `d3.js`, `jQuery`... a lot of js libraries.
However, I don't see it a "simple" web project because we have some scientific models that will be developed in `Python` (using scikit, numpy, etc) and which results will further be plotted on the `Leaflet.js` map. We are planning to it as a web project to easily share the results and because of the interactivity that we can achieve with `d3.js`.

Given that, I'm wondering which is a good approach for that. I don't know if I should somehow just to call the Python functions from a javacript file or if I should learn a framework such as `Django`... As I like to have in mind how my project is gonna be before starting the critical parts, I'm trying to visualize how to do that.

This may be closed or down voted, but any insight would be helpful.

Comment: I am sure SO moderators will close this question as it is too "wide", but I'll answer in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a great programming language as Python you have few options

- Publish results [as a IPython Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) - this seems to be the defacto standard for scientific community today. You can integrate `d3.js` and various other components to your notebooks. If you are a scientist or data analyst I would recommend exploring this option.
- Publish results as a static web site. Basically you generate a set of HTML files from Python templates offline, on your own computer. Then you upload the result somewhere. Or just zip them and email somewhere... it's easy because it is just bunch of files. [There exist many static website generators](http://staticsitegenerators.net/).
- Use a micro web framework, like [Pyramid](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). These are the solutions if you just want to have some dynamicity up and you do not e.g. need sign up, login and forgot password flow.
- Use non-micro web framework like Django - this gives you user management, object relationship mapping and probably some other stuff you are not going to need in scientific work.

For the two latter options you usually need to get a virtual machine (VPS) hosting or if you feel rich you can use Amazon EC2,  Microsoft Azure cloud or Heroku. Dynamic web hosting usually requires more money as you need to invest to your own server or application container. Furtermore this is much more complex process as you need to learn basics of full stack web programming.

[enter link description here](http://ipython.org/notebook.html)

Comment: Thank you for all the tips, @MikkoOhtamaa. (: